# Is there any RPG system made for a Wuxia campaign?

Tags: game-recommendation

I have searched over dozens of RPG systems and have only found systems for realism, horror, fantasy and sci-fi, but is there any RPG system that fits a Wuxia campaign?

Comment: There are piles of wuxia RPGs, some famous in their own right. (Search more; or ask on a discussion forum for posters to create a list of them.)